# Retrieving related models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to list all campaigns with their relations from database.
Here is the code for now.

Campaign.php

```
        public function task(){
            return $this->hasMany('Task','campaign_id');
        }
    }
?>
```

Task.php

```
        public function campaign(){
            return $this->belongsTo('Campaign','campaign_id');
        }
    }
?>
```

And Page controller

```
public function campaigns(){
    return View::make('pages.platform.campaigns')
    ->with('campaigns', Campaign::all());
}
```

It this case when I do this:

```
<pre>
    @foreach($campaigns as $c)
        <? print_r($c) ?>
    @endforeach
</pre>
```

I can't see the relations

```
[relations:protected] => Array()
```

How can I access this related models so I can echo them like

```
$c['name'] // Name field in Campaign table
$c['task']['name'] // Name field in related Task table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
foreach ($campaigns as $campaign)
{
  $campaign->name; // campaign model property

  foreach ($campaign->task as $task) // $campaign->task is a collection (hasMany relation)
  {
    $task; // related Task model
    $task->name; // with accessible all its properties
  }
}
```

but the above will cause database query for every campaign in the foreach loop, so in your controller change:

```
->with('campaigns', Campaign::all());
// to this:
->with('campaigns', Campaign::with('task')->get());
```

with() method is responsible for eager loading - check that as it's a must. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Then I suggest calling your relations appropriately to the relation itself, so singular for belongsTo or hasOne and plural for hasMany, belongsToMany, hasManyThrough etc.

That being said, I would call the relation of your like this:

```
// Campaign model
public function tasks()
{
  ...
}
```

Then of course you refer to 'tasks' in with() method instead of 'task'.

Comment: but if I use eager loading, will that display campaigns even if they are without tasks or only filtered to those wich has atleast one task?

Comment: All of them, for the latter you would use also has() or whereHas() method